# Generate multiple attribute?

Tags: c#, attributes, custom-attributes

ATM i cant quiet *imagine* how this will work. I'm sure it can be done. I notice a pattern use in my attribute where i always use 3 specific attributes together. Take the below as an example

```
    [MyAttr(4, @"a"),
     MyAttr(41, "b"),
     MyAttr(45, "ab")]
```

Mine is much more complicated but i would like to define one attribute with more params to generate the data above. How might i do that? Lets say my one attribute will look like this

```
MyAttr2(4, 41, "a", "b"); //4+41=45, "a"+"b" = "ab"
```

How might i generate the 3 MyAttr to apply to a class using MyAttr2?

Comment: Do you mean the same attribute with different constructors?

Comment: No i mean the code will look at MyAttr and there are 3 distinct instructions and i want to generate the 3 without adding logic to check the MyAttr2 and replicate the 3 instructions.

Comment: So, basically you want to have to access one single "MyAttr2" attribute which would propagate all the values placed in "MyAttr" attributes on the same type?

If so, could you make the "MyAtt2" as facade on top of any "MyAtt" attribute?

Comment: Marvin Smit: I think i could but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The C# compiler can't convert a single attribute entry into multiple ones** in the assembly metadata. However, you could model your attribute in such as way that it exposes additional attribute information as properties (or a collection). However, the child information will not be accessible directly via reflection as independent attributes.

Comment: Hmm, so do i need to modify my code logic for MyAttr? Or can i leave it alone and do what your suggesting with the limitation of child information not being accessible directly?

Comment: If you make the details part of a single attribute exposed via some collections/properties then you would need to change existing code. Which design better fits your needs is hard to say without more details about what you're doing and in how many cases you could consolidate multiple attributes. However, the child attribute approach would be a breaking change.